# When is the best time to include an ε-transitions in a NFA state diagram?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

While doing my NFA homework in my automata class, I feel like I'm not taking advantage of the ε-transitions I'm learning about. I can solve problems without using it. It's not like I really need it, except for when an empty string is part of the language, then I'll finally add an ε.

A lot of my text book examples use it which is why I feel bad not including it in the homework problems. I started this NFDA topic (using the "Introduction to theory of Computation" book) about last week and a half ago. Maybe I should wait it out a little longer?

Or are there a few shortcuts I could be using in my diagrams I should know about? What are your criteria for including ε-transitions in your diagrams?

Thank you.

Comment: Epsilon-transitions can always be eliminated. In fact, even non-determinism can always be eliminated. Epsilon-transitions are just supposed to make it easier for you to design your automata. If they don't, then you shouldn't worry about it and just ignore them.